# Is there a YouTube channel for Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

Does anyone have any thoughts on opening a YouTube channel for Stack Exchange physics?  This would be to better the quality of science education on YouTube.  If a transcript were included, that could be searched along with the title.  The videos would be under peer review as questions are in stack exchange.  It might be a way to add credibility to Physics videos that are on YouTube.  I know it wouldn't be practical to attempt to review the multitude of videos already there.  Rather, maybe people could submit their own videos to stack exchange as papers are submitted for peer review.  This is just the beginning of an idea I hoped could get discussed.  You have a good system here.  It might be a way for people to find good quality physics videos.  I have been viewing some topics for years on General Relativity and Quantum Mechanics, but am still searching for some answers that might be explained in a video format. Any suggestions, thoughts?

Comment: Are you volunteering?

Comment: I suspect that any Physics SE members who are really interested in making physics videos for YouTube would already be doing it.

Comment: beyond title, how do you search for contents on such a channel?

Comment: I don't understand this. Would someone just read through PSE questions on a video stream?

Comment: Well, we do have to counter the likes of "[Future Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-8JOkJyylvs)" (entirely hyperbole/clickbait titles. A computer voice, but very good. Like "Wonderful person" Petrov, but without any real content. Who can resist titles like *"Signs of life on Pluto!"* or *"Three Men Lost in Space"*?).

Comment: Apparently there is a YouTube tag for SE - https://www.youtube.com/hashtag/stackexchange